# How to get the length of every column in a kdb database?

Tags: kdb

We've seen issues where a kdb database is corrupted and are looking for a way to implement a check that every kdb column is the same length in a particular table. Any recommendation on how to do this?

i.e., would like to get a return value of each column in a table and it's length.

These tables have upwards of 200 columns. Any way to go about this efficiently?

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this might work for you.

```
q)tables[]
`positions`quote`trade
q)count each flip trade
time  | 40000
sym   | 40000
src   | 40000
price | 40000
amount| 40000
side  | 40000
```

You can run the same thing on partitioned data as well.

```
q)count each flip select from ohlc where date=last date
date     | 1440
sym      | 1440
exchange | 1440
timestamp| 1440
open     | 1440
high     | 1440
low      | 1440
close    | 1440
volume   | 1440
```

**EDIT**: The methods used above will only work on tables which are not corrupted, which may not be best suited to your use case.

If the data is corrupted, you can `get` each column from its location on disk and count it.

```
q)cols[ohlc]!{count get hsym`$"/path/to/hdb/2020.02.09/ohlc/",string x}each cols ohlc
date     | 1440
sym      | 1440
date     | 1440
exchange | 1440
timestamp| 1439
open     | 1440
high     | 1440
low      | 1440
close    | 1440
volume   | 1440
```

Comment: Is there an elegant way to iterate through multiple tables? i.e., group by tables?

Comment: ```tables[]!count''[flip each get each tables[]]``` creates a dict with each table as a key and its value being the dict of counts.

Comment: The fact that you can successfully execute `flip trade` or `select from ohlc where date=last date` means the tables in question do have columns of the same length. If the tables were corrupted your query would fail.

Comment: Good point @IgorKorkhov. Have made an edit to the original post.